# How to Decode the token used in URL through Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, url-parsing

When running a load test for 50 users with a steady state load of 15 mins, the samples do not go in the next loop, it means if we put a load of 50 users, in the sample tables for the first 50 samples there are no errors, however all the requests after that fail.

On log out we receive an authentication token
`BDT3-CHE8-GKA5-BWA1%7Cd67830e7c46bc1011d76e69de76c59c57c4f5956%7Clin`
and in the previous requests the token is
`BDT3-CHE8-GKA5-BWA1|d67830e7c46bc1011d76e69de76c59c57c4f5956|lin`
noticed that pipe (`|`) character in previous token is replaced by `%7C`.

Also the session ID is just generated on URL launch page, however not captured in Jmeter parameters and not used in further request.

Please provide more insights on this issue or a possible solution on how to decode the token, so it can be passed to the next request

Exception on Log out page is :

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 113: http://www.siteunderprogress.com/secure/WorkflowUIDispatcher.jspa?id=17116&action=11&atl_token=BDT3-CHE8-GKA5-BWA1|d67830e7c46bc1011d76e69de76c59c57c4f5956|lin&decorator=dialog&inline=true&_=1422286605586
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:283)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1141)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:431)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is the token in cookie data, in your page content, or literally part of the URL?  For example http://localhost/?token=TOKEN

Comment: Actually I am new to Jmeter, and when I am checking using fiddler, that token is in URL as well as in cookie also. <br/> ex : In URL it is **"secure/Logout!default.jspa?atl_token=BDT3-CHE8-GKA5-BWA1%7Cced230e879b9df57da3dba0cc5942572cf6c52bf%7Clin" ** and in cookie it is **".xsrf.token=BDT3-CHE8-GKA5-BWA1|ced230e879b9df57da3dba0cc5942572cf6c52bf|lin"**  and in page content it is **"secure/AddComment.jspa?atl_token=BDT3-CHE8-GKA5-BWA1%7Cced230e879b9df57da3dba0cc5942572cf6c52bf%7Clin\"**

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the  token from wherever you are more comfortable, (usually from the page) and then use it in all 3 places.
Use a regular expression post processor. See:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

When inserting into the URL, remember to encode it

Comment: Yes I did the same, but it didn't work for me.. same exception occurred as above

Comment: In the request above, the token is not encoded: there is a pipe character no allowed.